# Error incorrect function in XMLHttpRequest.open() method

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, javascript-objects, dom-events

I done a ajax call to local http server but I got error in  `xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost//push", true);` incorrect function in **IE 11**, Below is my full code:

```
var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
....some code.....
}}
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://localhost//push", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

IE uses `new XMLHttpRequest();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer very silly issue, In chrome URL can be `"http://localhost//push"` but in IE it should have **backslash** instead of forward slash  `"http:\\localhost\\push"` or else it will show **incorrect function**